# How do I make a bot to write out numbers counting up 1, 2 ,3 etc

Tags: python, numbers, counting

I am trying to make a bot that writes out numbers that counts up 1 by 1 and I want it to be like a keyboard stroke, but I have not been able to find anything about it, I am not very experienced with python or any coding languages.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```py
timestoloop = int(input("How many numbers would you like to count up? "))
number = 1 # the number starts at 1.
for x in range(timestoloop): # this will loop it the amount of times you entered into the input
    print(number)
    number += 1 # this will add 1 to it each time it loops.
```

+= adds 1 to the number each time it loops.
Hope this helps.

if you would like it to count up slowly you can use the time module to add a delay! Example:

```py
from time import sleep
sleep(1) #put how many seconds you would like the delay to be there, in this case it is 1 second.
```

Using PyAutoGui

```py
import pyautogui #if you haven't already use pip install pyautogui
timestoloop = int(input("How many numbers would you like to count up? "))
h = 1
for x in range(timestoloop): #you can also just put any number instead of the input if that's easier
    print(h)
    pyautogui.write(f" {h},") #this is what types it
    h += 1
```

Comment: I already have the counting bit done, it's the writing it out, as in it wrote it in lets say the search bar or anything

Comment: @sasa, Sorry but can you clarify a bit. Let's say my input is 10. What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: @sasa, Are you saying you want it to type it on your keyboard? for that I would use a module named [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @sasa, Alright I am pretty sure you want it to type it out for you on your keyboard, I edited my post to give you an example. Just for future notice include your current code in the post and make the title a bit simpler to understand and the text more in depth!

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @sasa, No problem. Good luck!